# Swift remove duplicates from array

Tags: swift, algorithm

I would like to optimise next algorithm, but have no idea how (without using swift functions such as .contains and etc.) Here it is:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    mutating private func removingDublicates(index: Int, countElements: Int) {
        if index == countElements {
            return
        }
        let comparable: Element = self[index]
        var dublicatesIndices: [Int] = []
        for i in index+1..<self.count {
            if comparable == self[i] {
                dublicatesIndices.append(i)
            }
        }
    
        dublicatesIndices.reversed().forEach { repeatedIndices in
            self.remove(at: repeatedIndices)
        }
        
        removingDublicates(index: index + 1, countElements: countElements - dublicatesIndices.count)
    }
    
    mutating func makeUniqueArray(completion: (Self.Element) -> Void) {
        removingDublicates(index: 0, countElements: self.count)
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: 1) {
            completion(self[i])
        }
    }
}
```

How it's working:

[1,2,2,2,3,4,5].makeUniqueArray {print ($0)} // output 1,2,3,4,5

Maybe is there any more elegant solutions how to implement supposed behaviour with less rows of code?  =)

Comment: Are the elements in initial array always sorted? Does the method needs to be mutating? Can't it return another array?